Solana Network not on wallet and I cant buy Solana nor receive it
I don't know If I am retarded but I swear my wallet is brocken. I was going to show images but it won't allow me to. Basically solana network is not on my wallet. When I click recieve the only networks that show up are eth polygon and base. However solana universal is there but I cant use this shit to traded meme coins.Even on the home solana is not there. If I try and buy solana doesnt come up. I live in california so its not illegal in my state. I dont have a vpn on. Someone please help me before I grab this shotgun and put it to good use thank you so much.

Can you please make sure you downloaded the phantom wallet from Apple App Store or the Google Play Store?
